# How to add custom fields in onestep checkout magento 1.9+

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, custom-fields, onestepcheckout

please, I need to know how to add custom fields in the magento's one step checkout billing address, such as: DNI, and 3 selects with department, province and district. This selects are customized by me, but I need to put them in the billing address. I want to know how to do that, step by step, if it's posible, with images.

I'll attach a screenshot.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUDKf.jpg)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Actually it seems to be a programming question. Magento doesn't have the feature of adding custom fields. Maybe there is a plugin or something somewhere, but all I could find were tutorials of how to implement this modifying Magento core.